# android network change broadcast receiver and getting network type

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephony

this is my receiver registered in my menifest file

```
     <receiver android:name=".Network_change" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
  </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

now what I am trying to do is whenever the network type is change like GSM to UMTS or EDGE to UMTS etc I want to get this type what I already did is I save network type when my app is started in previous_network_type  variable and in receiver

```
 current_network_type=telephony.getNetworkType();
```

after doing my work

```
      previous_network_type=current_network_type;
```

and these variables are static in a service and that service is running so the Problem is M getting 0 in both variables some time in one which is incorrect any help? coz 0 is unknown

Answer (score 1):

For what you say I understand you're not taking into account that every time the receiver is triggered it creates a new instance, which is destroyed after its work. Even with static variables you don't have persistent values.

One solution that worked for me is to use SharedPreferences. Be aware that on API11+ you should use the flag MODE_MULTI_PROCESS, something like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11)
   mySettings=context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
else 
   mySettings=context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",0);
int netType = mySettings.getBoolean("netType",0);
```

Hope it helps...